# How Is It Possible To Accumulate 2500 Reputation Points In A Week With A 200 Per Day Limit?

Tags: reputation, daily-reputation-limit, discussion

I'm astonished to see the results of the weekly reputation leagues.  It's hard enough to reach 200 in a given day, but averaging over 350 per day *for a whole week* is unbelievable.

It's supposed to be impossible without the aid of bounty questions or having each and every answer accepted.

It also helps to be toiling in the C#/.NET fields.  Together they represent 15% of the million questions asked on SO.  But even then you'd have to be a polymath with depth to accomplish this.

It goes without saying that my hat is off to those who regularly top the reputation rankings.  Your skills far exceed mine.

What explanations, beyond mere talent, can be offered to explain this?    Are there behaviors that I'm not aware of?

Comment: A single 500 rep bounty adds 71 rep/day for a week, too.  Get two of those and hit the rep cap every day, and you'd be nearly 350/day, *before* counting accepted answers.

Comment: How frequent is a 500 rep bounty hit?  I'll have to check the data.  Thanks, Roger.

Comment: Nick is the king of hill right now.  He gets a *lot* of answer marks every day.  It takes 10 to get 350 rep per day, he often gets more.

Comment: Just a clue: you know the shopping, mountain climbing, promenades with your family, cycling, cinema, video and theater, gardening, reading or sports, restaurants, friends... or, even, work: just stop all of that and spend 20h a day on SO.

Comment: No thanks, ring0, but great advice nonetheless.

Comment: I like your user name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accepted answers are not limited by the rep cap.  You *always* get that 15 points.

Comment: Yes, I think I said that.  I'll have to check out the SO data dump and see if that explains it entirely.  Why speculate when you have data?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Why do there have to be any other explanations? Basically it's in accepted answers.

Nick Craver in particular beats my rep almost every single day - and it's all through accepted answers, with a very occasional bounty. It's far from unusual for Nick to receive in excess of 500 rep in a day, which is the 200 from votes and *20* accepted answers. I've only done that a handful of times, but for Nick it's a regular occurrence.

Oh, and Nick doesn't have the benefit of many C#/.NET answers - his are mostly on jQuery. Don't forget that a popular field will get more questions but *also* more answers. It's good to be in a popular field in terms of votes, but not in terms of accepted answers.

Comment: We'll have to come up with "Nick Facts"

Comment: I'm beginning to think Nick knows more about jQuery than Mr Resig himself.

Comment: [ **This week** ](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2010-08-09) Nick averaged 504 a day for a week. Looks like an all time weekly record.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, although that week included 700 points from bounties. Without those bounties, I'd have actually *beaten* Nick that week, just for a change.